# Get inside contours with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I would like to get contours of shape not outside of it, but inside:
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiTu9.png)

I am using python opencv ubuntu

Answer (score -1):

You can use Morphological filters such as erosion then detect contour, you can check [this](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html)